# How to get clear from " method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node" error?

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

I am tring to get an xml doc in my appBut I am getting an error in getTextContent() as "method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node".I have also added the required packages at the top for it.I have also tried xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar & tried the quick fix of casting it also. I have add this part of this code,

fullReport.append(docs.getElementsByTagName("report").item(0).getTextContent());

Please tell me how can I correct this one.Thanks a million mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one reason may be is that getTextContent () is not defined under type Element dut to the fact your Android project target version should be less than 2.2.It is only available in the higher version of Android to enhance the lower version.Just try updating your version 2.2 or more.Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the order of the imports. Take a look at http://www.enterprisesearchblog.com/2009/09/fix-for-gettextcontent-is-undefined-for-the-type-node-for-solr-project-in-eclipse-ide.html